# Why does this limit exist even though there are infinite limiting values?

Tags: calculus

[image]

According to wolfram alpha and my textbook, this limit exists simply by plugging in the values to get 6/5.
However, if you approach along y=mx, then the expression becomes $\frac{2+m^2}{1+m^2}$, which means the limit depends on m and has infinite values, thus does not exist.

My hunch is this reasoning is incorrect because when you set $y=mx$, you aren't actually approaching $(-1,2)$ without limiting m to be $m=-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @JPMarciano's answer, I have found that if you let
$y=mx+c$ so that it can truly approach any point, then $y=mx+c$ becomes $m=c-2$ after plugging in (-1,2).
If you then substitute $y=mx+c$ into the original expression you get the following, which evaluates to 6/5!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Analysing approaches along lines, you would have to use the equations $y=m(x+1)+2$. Put it in the limit and you will see that it works.

Comment: Thanks, this works...and it works in the generic y=mx+c case as well!